# Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(…) is not a function, putting semicolon like I've read online is not working

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm making a little mockup restaurant page for the odin project to start getting familiar with webpack, when I've run into this annoying error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) , (void (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...))) is not a function
```

Here is my code, and it says it's happening on line 36 (which is the line saying "navBar()" in the makePage function):

```
function makeBackground() {
    const background = document.createElement('div');
    background.classList.add("background");
    document.body.appendChild(background);
};
function navBar() {
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const header = document.createElement('header');
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    const nav = document.createElement('nav');

    content.append(header);
    header.append(nav);
    nav.append(ul);

    const home = document.createElement('li');
    home.setAttribute("id", 'home');
    home.textContent = "Home";
    ul.append(home);

    const menu = document.createElement("li");
    menu.setAttribute('id', 'menu');
    menu.textContent = "Menu";
    ul.append(menu);

    const contact = document.createElement('li');
    contact.setAttribute('id', 'contact');
    contact.textContent = "Contact";
    ul.append(contact);
};

function makePage() {
    makeBackground();
    navBar();
};

export default makePage();
```

I then export that function to my index.js, and call the function there.

Comment: first of all, remove the `;` after the function closing `}` - that is NOT the problem, but they are certainly not needed there ... secondly .. `export default makePage;` without the `()` - otherwise you're exporting what `makePage` function *returns* - which is, undefined, since it doesn't return anything - I doubt this one change will fix everything, since you seem to have a very deep `fn(.....)(.....)(....)(....)` somewhere

Comment: `export default makePage();` Don't call the export...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do `export default makePage;` without the (). Using `export default makePage();` exports `makePage` function returns that is undefined. So Try this:

```
function makeBackground() {
    const background = document.createElement('div');
    background.classList.add("background");
    document.body.appendChild(background);
}
function navBar() {
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const header = document.createElement('header');
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    const nav = document.createElement('nav');

    content.append(header);
    header.append(nav);
    nav.append(ul);

    const home = document.createElement('li');
    home.setAttribute("id", 'home');
    home.textContent = "Home";
    ul.append(home);

    const menu = document.createElement("li");
    menu.setAttribute('id', 'menu');
    menu.textContent = "Menu";
    ul.append(menu);

    const contact = document.createElement('li');
    contact.setAttribute('id', 'contact');
    contact.textContent = "Contact";
    ul.append(contact);
}

function makePage() {
    makeBackground();
    navBar();
}

export default makePage;
```

Comment: gotta love the old *"try this" with no explanation* answer

Comment: Yeah man, sorry . I update the answer @Bravo

Comment: nah, all good - I sometimes post answer like that to people that show no effort :p